# javascript перезагрузка функции

Tags: javascript, функции

Задача сделать форму..с указанием время начала и время конца

при (повторном) выборе значения . функция init() не перезагружается =( то есть суммирует значения

Подскажите как это исправить. Заранее спасибо .

```js
function init(hours_now) {
    $('.up-hours').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        var count = parseInt($input.val()) + 1;
        count = count >= 24 ? hours_now : count;
        $input.val(count);
        $input.change();
        return false;
    });

    $('.down-hours').click(function () {
        var $hours = $(this).parent().find('.hours');
        var count = parseInt($hours.val()) - 1;
        count = count < hours_now ? hours_now : count;
        $hours.val(count);
        $hours.change();
        return false;
    });

    $('.up-minutes').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        var count = parseInt($input.val()) + 15;
        count = count >= 60 ? 0 : count;
        $input.val(count);
        $input.change();
        return false;
    });


    $('.down-minutes').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 15;
        count = count < 0 ? 0 : count;
        $input.val(count);
        $input.change();
        return false;
    });
}


function today() {
      var now = new Date();
      var hours_now = now.getHours();
      var minutes_now = now.getMinutes();
       var $start_hours  = $('.up-hours').parent().find('input');
       $start_hours.val(hours_now +1);
       init(hours_now);
}

function tomorrow() {
      var tomorrow = new Date();
      tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    init(9);
}

function later() {
    init(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label for="start" class="control-label">Начало:</label>
       <div class="input-group">
           <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" onclick="today()"  style="width: 100px;">Cегодня</button>
       </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary " onclick="tomorrow()" style="width: 100px;">Завтра</button>
          </div>
        <div class="input-form" >
       <input type="button" id="start" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="later()" style="width: 100px;" >
         </div>

    </div><!--col-sm-4-->
    <div class="form-group" >
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="clockdiv" >
            <div>
                <div class="up-hours">+</div>
                <input class="hours" value="1" readonly/>
                <div class="down-hours">-</div>
                <div class="smalltext">Часов</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="up-minutes">+</div>
                <input class="minutes" value='0' readonly/>
                <div class="down-minutes">-</div>
                <div class="smalltext">Минут</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--col-sm-4-->
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="clockdiv" >

            <div>
                <div class="up-hours">+</div>
                <input class="hours" value="1"  readonly/>
            <div class="down-hours">-</div>
                <div class="smalltext">Часов</div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="up-minutes">+</div>
                <input class="minutes" value='0' readonly/>
                <div class="down-minutes">-</div>
                <div class="smalltext">Минут</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--col-sm-4-->
</div>
```

Не хочет он выполняться на jsfiddle .
Попробую пояснить : когда пользователь кликает на + значение   увеличивается на N значение ,которое было передано в функцию init() вызванную в функции today() или $tomorrow с разными параметрами init()ведет себя не правильно

Comment: ссылочку бы jsfiddle

Comment: Ничего непонятно, читать лень, а проблема, скорее всего, в том, что от событий надо отписываться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, поехали.

Каждый раз, когда вызывается функция `init`, она добавляет новые обработчики события `click` элементов `'.up-hours'`, `'.down-hours'`, `'.up-minutes'`, `'.down-minutes'`. Нажмите два раза кнопку "Сегодня", а потом "+" часов - заметьте, на сколько увеличивается значение в инпуте.

```
function init(hours_now) {
  $('.up-hours').off('click');
  $('.up-hours').click(function () {
    ...
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло !